# Knockout + customBinding not updating

Tags: knockout.js

I have a quick question about customBindings, hopefully some could help explain to me?  I thought that when an observable is updated that any customBinding that is bound to that observable would have its "update" method called.  I can see that when I update my observable that other subscribers are being notified, but it doesn't seem that the customBinding is being called.

Here is my viewModel:

```
var innerModel = {
    name: ko.observable('junk')
};

var innerModel2 = {
    name: ko.observable('junk2')
};

var viewModel = {
    im1: innerModel,
    im2: innerModel2,
    selectedModel: ko.observable({name:'xxx'})
};
```

and here is my customBinding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.custom = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        console.log("BAM!");
        while (element.firstChild)
            ko.removeNode(element.firstChild);

        ko.renderTemplate('test', valueAccessor(), {}, element, 'replaceNode');

    }  
};
```

where my template is simply a span that displays the "name" field:

```
<script id='test' type='text/html' charset='utf-8'>
<span data-bind='text: name'></span>
</script>
```

Here is the HTML that I use with the customBinding:

```
<div id="container" data-bind="with: viewModel">
    <div data-bind="custom: selectedModel">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I update selectedModel to either of the two innerModels, the correct name is displayed but the customBinding's 'update' function isn't being called.  I have a separate subscriber to the "selectedModel" observable:

```
viewModel.selectedModel.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue.name());
});
```

and that is called when I change the selectedModel, so why isn't the customBinding's update being called?

Here is a jsfiddle that shows the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/gperng/twAcJ/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

You need to call the following function to make it work:

```
var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())
```

Try this fiddle for more: http://jsfiddle.net/twAcJ/13/

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me. It only prints "BAM!" once, ever. Despite pressing all buttons multiple times. Note that I selected knockout 3.0.0 (though 2.3.0 didn't work either).

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `with` is wrong in this case.  If you use this, it'll work as you expect:

```
<div id="container" data-bind="with: selectedModel">
    <div data-bind="custom: $data">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is because in your example the `custom` binding is not on the selectedModel, but on the entire viewModel itself which does not change.

Here's the jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/soniiic/twAcJ/7/

Comment: I'm not 100% that makes sense.  If I take out the div with the "with" binding, I still run into the same issue as before (where the custom binding's update handler is not being called despite the observable being changed).  Also, in your example, the "init" of the custom binding is being called every time (because the parent with is the observable and it has changed, so all child elements below are re-rendered).  See http://jsfiddle.net/gperng/6nw8B/, I added an "init" function and you can see that the binding is getting re-initialized every time.